# HTTParty post record using with -u flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, curl, httparty

I'm trying to post the data using following API using `HTTParty gem` in rails,

```
curl -X POST https://app.referralsaasquatch.com/api/v1/{tenant_alias}/user \
-u API_KEY: \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "id": "219065",
    "accountId": "accc9065",
    "referralCode": "BOBTESTERSON",
    "email": "bob@example.com",
    "imageUrl": "https://www.example.com/profiled/ab5111251125",
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Testerson" }'
```

What is best way to achieve this goal?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try Restclient(https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem to achieve this goal. It is good for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

A solution could look a bit like this, where the `basic_auth`argument stands for  the `curl -u`part. Since you are only passing the api_key, the follwoing should do the trick. It's looking weird but it is the way to go:

```
class MyRequest
   include HTTParty
   base_uri 'https://testdomain.org/api/v1'

   def self.execute(query)
       post('/updates/create.json', :query =>  query, basic_auth: {username: "YOUR_API_KEY", password: ""})
   end 
 end
```

Comment: but looks like he needs to send `APIKEY` rather than `uname` and `password`.. can you address that as well?

Comment: Sure. I added a more explicit example to my answer.